# How to extract data from database and use in jsp page

Tags: jsp, servlets

I'm working on jsp,servlet code . I have `LESSON` table in my db too which has `lesson_id` , `lesson_name` and etc.

Now I want to use `"a"` tag in my jsp page which link to a servlet page but each tag used in jsp should has a specific `lesson_id` which has token from my database.

for example data structure has a special id. so if i want to use many `"a"` tag in my jsp for each lesson that has a specific id, how can i do this?

Comment: if u really wanna learn jsp with JDBC, i'll suggest not to do java code on jsp.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use [JSTL](https://jstl.java.net/) & [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info). For database access use JSTL [SQL Tag library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnald.html).

JSP: (sample code:)

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sql" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<sql:setDataSource var="webappDataSource"
    driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test"
    user="root" password="root" />

<sql:query dataSource="${webappDataSource}"
    sql="select lesson_id, lesson_name from lessons" var="result" />

<table width="100%" border="1">
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
        <tr>
            <td>${row.lesson_id}</td>
            <td>${row.lesson_name}</td>
            <td>
               <a href="${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}/servletURL/${row.lesson_id}">
                  click here
               </a>
            </td>               
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

**Note:** It's better to move the database code in the Servlet. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19090153/dynamic-database-table-display-using-jstl)

Comment: glad to know it. If the issue is resolved then close the thread. [visit](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: JSTL SQL and XML taglibs are for prototyping only. Don't use them in production applications. See also 1st paragraph on the Java EE tutorial you linked.

Comment: @BalusC I have already added a note for the same to move the database logic on server side with working example. Thanks for making it more clear.